# WPF TabControl default to vertically stacked tabs

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I just started using Microsoft WPF to try  to make a simple GUI for a small program and ran into trouble when I wanted a TabControl.
When I drag it in from the toolbox it looks like this:

[Default TabControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VwRd.png)

As you can see the tabs are on the top but stacked vertically and I can't figure out how to make them horizontal. I've tried using the TabStripPlacement option but that just moves the packet of tabs to a different side of the TabControl, it doesn't organize the tabs in relation to each other.

So to be clear: I want the tabs on top, but I want them side by side, like the normal tab arrangement, which seems to be the default for everyone except me.

Comment: "I want the tabs on top, but I want them side by side," isn't very clear! Is it just that there's not enough horizontal space?

Comment: If giving it enough space to display the headers you gave it isn't an option, you could try making the font really really tiny and give them single-letter names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default behavior when the horizontal space cannot occupy the tabs horizontally.

[image]

So you need to give it more space. Preventing this behavior isn't trivial, but is [possible](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/277bb9d9-d082-4ca8-929c-65ede8aead2a/how-to-prevent-tabcontrol-from-doing-multi-rows?forum=wpf).